# Function is not calling mocked constructor in Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I have a setup similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084528/mocking-a-function-jest-but-jest-calling-original-function) but the partial mocking answer is not working for me.

I have a file 'FiscalYear.jsx' which contains a class `FiscalYear` and a few related non-class functions eg

```
export class FiscalYear {
    constructor(fy) { //does stuff }
    // other functionality
}

export function getFY(offset) {
    // does stuff
    return new FiscalYear(fy);
}
```

I want my Jest test for the `getFY` function to simply check that the `FiscalYear` constructor was called with the right parameter. I used partial mocking in my test file to accomplish this:

```
import { FiscalYear, getFY } from '../FiscalYear';

jest.mock('../FiscalYear', () => {
    const originalModule = require.requireActual('../FiscalYear');
   
    return {
        ...originalModule,
        FiscalYear: jest.fn().mockImplementation((a) => { })
    };
});

test("getFY", () => {
    getFY(2);
    expect(FiscalYear).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I'll update the `toHaveBeenCalled` to `toBeCalledWith` once I make it actually call the function. However currently the test fails with

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

I put a console.log in the real constructor and confirmed that the `getFY` function is calling that instead of the mock constructor.

How to get this working? Is it a bad design to have these both in the same file? Totally new to JavaScript so if this is bad practice please let me know.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue